# Parallel execution of for loop in django functions

Tags: python, django, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a function and this function goes to 10 different sites and retrieves data with a GET request.
This is how I do it inside the for loop.

**WebSite.objects.all();** The database that I saved in a different area on django.

```
web_site = WebSite.objects.all():
for web in web_site:
    get information from web
```

I want to run this for loop in parallel.

How can I achieve this, is there an easy way? I can also implement it directly in func code or try a feature of django/celery.